ros2 humble with ur3e and robotiq 2f-85 gripper
im new to ros2 and im sorry but i really really need some help here...
i've download the ur-robot-driver for ros2 humble for the ur3e and it works very well with my python script(using action client and action server) but i cant find a driver for ros2 humble for the 2f-85 robotiq gripper , i need this driver for closing/opening the gripper from my python script (i mean ros2 humble python script, not some other scripts or methods...)
please help if you can, its been a month of no advancing for me as im stuck on this and couldn't get any help elsewhere...
Thanks a lot!
Itzik

https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros2_robotiq_gripper should work.
I believe it's what I've used to control the 2F85 on Humble.

wow thank you so much for the quick answer! i didnt recieve a nortification which sucks... should i just clone the repo to my ros2_ws (into src) and build it regularly?

You'll want to check out the humble branch of the repo and also clone and check out the ros2 branch of the serial repo here: https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/ros2_robotiq_gripper/blob/humble/ros2_robotiq_gripper.humble.repos
